# How can I reference an intersection table of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I am creating a pharmacy database that handles prescriptions. When designing the database, I took into consideration that doctors can work at many offices, and an office can be home to many doctors, so I created the following many to many relationship:

```
doctor:

| id | name | // more

office:

| id | name | address | // more

doctors_offices:

| doctor_id | office_id |
```

I followed the design I've seen in my database textbooks as well as many online resources, but I'm now running into a little confusion when trying to create a `prescription` table. In this table I want to know not only which doctor wrote the prescription, but at which location.

I find myself having a few options:

- Add an auto_increment key to the `doctors_offices` table to have a unique identifier for each dr/office pairing
- Add a composite foreign key to the prescription table that references `doctors_offices`. (Is this possible?)
- Add two foreign keys to prescription table. One that references `doctors` and one that references `offices`.

Which of these options is most normalized? I know that the third one is likely the *least* normalized, as it opens up the possibility that I select an office that a doctor does not belong to, but I felt important to mention as it might be a common instinct among some beginner database designers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more flexible if you save the `doctor_id` as well as the `location_id` along with the prescriptions data. Otherwise, you will run into difficulties if a doctor moves to another office after already having given some prescriptions, unless you make a new entry for every time period a doctor was present in a certain office. Furthermore, you won't be able to properly depict the situation when, exceptionally, another doctor is present in the office and makes a prescription despite he or she has no office assignment.

People tend to become ingenious if the system prevents them from inserting data for a technical reason, you should always consider such exceptions, because they will occur.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Now, it seems like a double edged sword. On one hand, a doctor can prescribe from any office, and any office can give a prescription from any doctor, which is added flexibility. However, it opens up the risk of inaccuracies if a doctor never visited a certain office. But my application would have no way of verifying that anyways, right? That would be user error if they made an incorrect pairing.

Comment: As of my experience, too much restriction is tempting users to type in incorrect data. There is some information which has to be saved as fast as possible, and most of the users don't know about your database design and end up bypassing your restriction by entering wrong data - as incorrect as necessary to save it.

Comment: Good point. As far as the prescription aspect is concerned then, I won't concern my intersection table. I will still keep it for other aspects of the application, of course. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I keep thinking about a scenario in which a doctor works at multiple offices but (s)he is not allowed to prescribe medications on a given (specific) office. Not sure it's a realistic scenario though. Supposing it is, that information, I believe, would be related to the `doctors_offices`, and by not using its PK in the relationship, you kinda lose that flexibility.

Comment: Yet, I agree with the point raised by @Œlrim since the question is only related to the relationship between prescriptions->(doctors,offices). The prescription itself doesn't need to know these details. As suggested, you might store both ids (doctor, office) in the prescription and this will give all the information you need for that prescription. +1 then :-)